# jquery tmpl formatting a date?

Tags: jquery, json, templates

I am using jquery tmpl to show a bunch of results in a table. One of them is a date which I am outputting using this in my template:

```
<td class="textAlignRight">${EffectiveDate}</td>
```

but it comes out formatted like "/Date(1245398693390)/". How can I change it so that it comes out formatted like m/dd/yyyy h:mm tt?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply use a function to format your date:

Template:

```
<td class="textAlignRight">${GetDate(EffectiveDate)}</td>
```

Function:

```
function GetDate(jsonDate) {
  var value = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
  return value.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + value.getDate() + "/" + value.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: where exactly need to paste the GetDate() function?
in `ready`?

Answer (score 2):

```
<td class="textAlignRight">{{= format(new Date(parseInt(EffectiveDate.substr(6))), 'd') }}</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    Date.prototype.CustomFormat = function () {
        return this.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + this.getDate() + "/" + this.getFullYear();
    };
</script>
```

...

```
<td class="textAlignRight">${EffectiveDate.CustomFormat()}</td>
```