# formatting json date in javascript template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

My controller sends date data to the view using JSON. On the view I'm sending those data to a jQuery template to display. My problem is date, since I'm getting this value like

```
"/Date(1245398693390)/"
```

So I've tried with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443654/jquery-tmpl-formatting-a-date) but using FireBug I can see that an error is thrown at line

```
var value = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

with the error

> `jsonDate.substr is not a function`

If it's important at all I'm trying to implement this using jQuery mobile.

Update

```
<script id="myDataTemplate" type="text/html">          
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("${GetDateString(Date)}", "Fetch", "Data")</li>            
</script>
```

and this is js function injected in Layout view

```
<script>
            function getDateString(jsonDate) {
                if (jsonDate == undefined) {
                    return "";
                }
                var utcTime = parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6));

                var date = new Date(utcTime);
                var minutesOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset();

                return date.addMinutes(minutesOffset).toString("M/d/yyyy h:mm tt");
            }
        </script>
```

Update 2
This is js function I originally used

```
function GetDate(jsonDate) {
  var value = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6))); //breaks
  return value.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + value.getDate() + "/" + value.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: what you're getting back is actually javascript code, not json proper. what this means is that if you execute that code, it will generate a new `Date` object starting at the #milliseconds since unix epoch date. in other words, you need to treat that value as JSONP.

Comment: @Kristian thanks for your time. Question is updated. Can you please add solution with concrete example.

Comment: so, when you console out the `jsonDate` var you get `"/Date(1245398693390)/"`?

Comment: I've just posted originally used js functon. It breaks on var value = ... line. Ofcourse I've used @Html.ActionLink("${GetDate(Date)}"...

Comment: yes, that is because the value of jsonDate is not a proper string. thus the function `substr` is unavailable. therefore, in order to continue debugging this, you need to throw a `console.log` inside of that function just before the breaking line to identify exactly what the value of jsonDate is, and make sure that it is actually a string.

Comment: Few solutions here ---- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json

Comment: wow -- /Date(1245398693390)/  its the exact value as the one in the 2009 post

Comment: yep, copied that value when try to test. So any concrete solution?

Comment: did you see this solution ---    var milli =     "/Date(1245398693390)/".replace(/\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\//, '$1');
     var d = new Date(parseInt(milli));

Comment: the above didn't work in the console --- this does though  ---  var aa = "/Date(1245398693390/".match(/\d+/);  ----  var bb = parseInt(aa);   ----   var date = new Date(bb);  ---   alert(date);   ---- try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working test

```
   var aa = "/Date(1245398693390/".match(/\d+/); 

   var bb = parseInt(aa);

   var date = new Date(bb);

   alert(date);
```

[image]

Comment: :))) i think its time i signed up to that, i never used it. Cheers